# Number of unique users fired a specific event Using Google Analytics segments

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to find the number of unique users who fired the event of enabling the widget using Google Analytics.

I created a segment based on the relevant Category and Action of this event but I'm not sure if I should filter it by users or by sessions- can someone please explain the difference.

Moreover, I'm not sure on which number I should look after applying this segment. Should I look on:
Audience-> Overview-> users 
Audience-> Active users 
Behaviour-> events-> unique events
 
can someone please explain the difference of these three numbers.

Thanks in advance

Liran.

Comment: This is off topic as it's not related to programming. You should post this to Webmasters instead.